# Convert webm to mp4 using FFMPEG via RecordRTC

Tags: angular, typescript, ffmpeg, webrtc, recordrtc

I have an angular application where I am using RecordRTC to record audio + video, the video is getting stored in webm format but I want to convert it into mp4, for that I am using FFMPEG library.
I am getting an issue where I have installed @ffmpeg/ffmpeg [^0.12.7] @ffmpeg/core [0.12.4]

Now I am trying to call it in my .ts file

```
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
```

But getting an issue TS2305: Module '"../../../../../node_modules/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg/dist/esm"' has no exported member 'createFFmpeg'. TS2305: Module '"../../../../../node_modules/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg/dist/esm"' has no exported member 'fetchFile'.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @rockbass2560 decided to do the processing on the backend itself.